# why underscores are not recommended for variable names in Julia?

Tags: julia

I read in the Julia doc page [https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables/#:~:text=Variable%20names%20must%20begin%20with,Sm%20math%20symbols](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables/#:%7E:text=Variable%20names%20must%20begin%20with,Sm%20math%20symbols))%20are%20allowed. :

> Word separation can be indicated by underscores ('_'), but use of
> underscores is discouraged unless the name would be hard to read
> otherwise

My question is if there any reasons to discourage the usage of underscores? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think underscores are really discouraged in user code and for internal variables. It is mostly for being consistent with the style in Base Julia, which follows this, mostly. And consistency is good, right?

But if you create a package or module, then the interface normally consists of types and functions. Typenames have strong convetion that they should be CapitalCase. User-facing functions are normally lowercase without `_`, because they are supposed to be simple, brief and should express a single well-defined concept. A bit like the Unix philospophy: every function should do one thing, and do it well.

A convention discouraging composite and long identifier names encourages you to create simple functions. If your function needs a name with underscores, it's possibly a sign that you should break it into multiple functions.

But in your own code, use whatever convension that suits you.

Answer (score 3):

I’m no expert on Julia, but the line you quote is located under the header “Stylistic Conventions” and I would presume that’s basically it.

There is an additional section about naming conventions in the docs under [Style Guide](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Use-naming-conventions-consistent-with-Julia-base/)
There is a line in there that says:

> “Underscores are also used to indicate a combination of concepts”.

So if you decided to use a lot of underscores in your function names, the next programmer to work on your code might think you are “combining concepts”.